# How can i create different pages without using activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to create an app that has different pages for topics and questions. I have created about two activites and am about to create more, like 40 activities. How can I do this without creating up to that number of activities?

Here is my MainActivity.java codes

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mListView;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Declare the text view id
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);

        //Adding text to the array list
        String booksArray[] = new String[]{"General Questions", "Mathematics",
                "Physics",
                "Chemistry",
                "English"};

        //Initialize the array list in the adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout
                .simple_list_item_1, booksArray);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Set the listener for the list view item
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                //if the position of item clicked is 1, it should open
                //another activity
                if(position == 1 ){
                    conditionOfIf();
                }

                else{
                    //A short message that notify user for an error
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please click on the first objcet",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();}
            }
        });
    }

    //The real code that open another activity called Topics
    private void conditionOfIf(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Topics.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone that responded to my question, including the guy that down voted my post.

Comment: Seriously??? 40 activities??? Are you sure that what you can do can not be done with just 2 or 3 activities that receive different parammeters? Maybe your app requisites need 40 activities but I think you must think the architecture twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) is your answer. your can create 40 fragments and have only one activity for managing that fragments.
And the best thing about fragments is that you can use the same UI for multiple purpose i.e reuse-ability which might come handy as you have large number of layouts.

i think this will be a great [Fragment tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html) to start with,it is easy to understand yet powerful enough to teach you the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

use fragments.
For learning fragments go to google or youtube videos.
There are many online sources available.